# How to access element in MapItemsControl on WP 8.1 RT?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I'm working on Windows Phone 8.1 RT project and i want to display information when i tap on a pin.

```
<Maps:MapControl 
        Center="{Binding ViewStoreModel.loc, Converter={StaticResource GeoPointConvertCenter}}"
        x:Name="Map" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,101,0,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Height="539"  Width="400"
        ZoomLevel = "8"
        LandmarksVisible = "True"
        TrafficFlowVisible = "True"
        PedestrianFeaturesVisible = "False"
        MapServiceToken="{StaticResource MapServiceTokenString}"  >
        <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapIcons" ItemsSource="{Binding ViewStoreModel.loc2}"  >
            <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:Name="Temp">
                    <StackPanel Tapped="Image_Tapped" x:Name="MyStack"  Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Geopoint, Converter={StaticResource GeoPointConvertCenter}}" 
                                Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="{Binding Anch, 
                                Converter={StaticResource NormalizedAnchorPointConverter}}">
                        <Image x:Name="MyImage" Source="{Binding BitmapImage}" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="DisplayInformation" Text="Adress" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </DataTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl>

    </Maps:MapControl>
```

In order to display the pin's information, I create a tapped event on the image element:

```
        private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        StackPanel s = sender as StackPanel;
        TextBox text = s.FindName("DisplayInformation") as TextBox;
        text.Visibility = Windows.UI.Xaml.Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

The pin's information display well but when i re-tape i want to hide the previous pin's information and display the new.

How can I browse the MapItemsControl element in order to hide all pin's information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can add bool (or Visibility) property into your ViewStoreModel.loc2 datamodel and bind it to visibility of DisplayInformation. Then, in your Image_Tapped, set all as false and in s.DataContext (where is you binding item stored) set this property as true.